# Example of an infinite algebraic field extension which is not simple

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I want to an example of an infinite algebraic field extension that is not simple. I was thinking of the algebraic numbers $\mathbb{A}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, or all the square roots of primes adjoined to $\mathbb{Q}$ as an example, but I wasn't sure how to show it is never equal to $\mathbb{Q}(\theta)$ for any $\theta$.

Answer (score 1):

Simple algebraic extensions are finite. Since $[\overline{\Bbb Q}:\Bbb Q]=\infty$, we are done. The extension $\overline{\Bbb Q}\mid \Bbb Q$ cannot be simple.

References:

[An algebraic simple extension has finite degree](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2557800/an-algebraic-simple-extension-has-finite-degree)

[Algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{C}$. Alternative proof?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2723977/algebraic-closure-of-mathbbq-in-mathbbc-alternative-proof)